# Port scanning on server

Tags: nmap, ports

My use case is to check open ports on multiple servers, so when I try:

```
nmap -iL list.txt
```

then nmap only scans for some particular ports whether they are open or closed, but when I try:

```
namp -p 1-1000 192.168.1.1
```

it checks for every single port whether it is open or not but it is limited to only one IP/server.

I want to perform a scan on multiple servers at one time.

The following did not work:

```
nmap -p 1-1000 192.168.1.1/20
```

It gave error.

Comment: How about: nmap -v -A -T5 -p1-65535 -iL list.txt

Comment: Thanks, it is working. What attribute in above command is only responsible  for checking open ports. I don't want to do service scans etc, only want to do port scanning. which attribute should i remove in command?

Comment: Lose the -v -A -T5. Please note that this is only for TCP ports and will not scan for open UDP ports.

Comment: man nmap is your friend.

Comment: "It gave error." What error?

Comment: `192.168.1.1/20` should be: `192.168.1.0/20`. Perhaps you mean: `192.168.1.0/24` ?